# Upgrade to Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.0.0 or higher. how can I know my version & update?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, admob

I publish my app in dec-2015 with eclipse, I receive mail for upgrade to Google Mobile Ads SDK 7.0.0 or higher. how can I know my version? and how can I update in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the most recent version when you published, you should be fine:

- [Mobile Ads SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/release-notes)

I should mention, though, that Google has deprecated support for building Android apps in Eclipse. I'd recommend converting your project to Android Studio if you haven't already, since the `google_play_services_lib` used for Eclipse builds is no longer distributed.

Comment: I am using the same version in my app
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
Now should i do some thing else or my project will be ok and it will show ads after jan 23 2018? please help i am very confuse